# How do I create a page of answers to questions written in my text?

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

What I want is very similar to what Table of Contents does, but I don't know how to implement it.  Throughout my text, I have questions that students will answer.  What I want is to also place answers there in-line with the latex code that will show up in an appendix numbered to match the problem it came from.

Example:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{History of Computers}%Lesson 1 - History of Computers
%<... Text Body...>

\M In what year was the ABC computer made? %Question 1
\Answer{1939}
\M What does ENIAC stand for? %Question 2
\Answer{Electronic Numerical Integrator and Calculator}
%<... More questions...>

%end of tex file
\PrintMasteries

\end{document}
```

Where `\M` auto-generates numbers using the counter "Masteries", which resets when the chapter changes (this allows me to have different sections of questions separated by text and not have to search the previous text for what number I left off--especially if I add/remove questions).    `\PrintMasteries` will have an output that looks something like this:

```
Lesson 1 - History of Computers
   1. 1939
   2. Electronic Numerical Integrator and Calculator
   %<...Answers to other questions...>
```

I don't want to manually type-set this, and I want to have the flexibility that `\chapter` and `\section` commands have--meaning I can switch questions and answer pairs around and the appendix file generates them in the correct order with the correct numbering.

What I envision working is a file, like the `.toc` file, that has lines added to it whenever I use the `\Answer` command (much like `\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{<response to \chapter>}` does when you type `\chapter{}`).  I've tried searching for the code to `\tableofcontents` because I believe that would help tremendously, but I can't find that.  That alone would probably get me far enough to do what I need to do.

Thanks for your help in advance and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: A minimal *compilable* example is always preferred. There are probably solutions to this already, but one can create a home made one easily.

Comment: The `answers` package was designed to do just this.

Comment: I looked at the `answers` package and  couldn't get much sense about what was going on without compiling it and studying it in great detail.  It looks like it would do exactly the kind of thing I would like, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\masterieslist{}
\def\printmasteries{\appto\masterieslist{\end{enumerate}}\masterieslist}
\let\originalchapter\chapter
\def\chapter#1#{\chapteraux{#1}}
\def\chapteraux#1#2{\originalchapter#1{#2}%
  \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\masterieslist}
    {\eappto\masterieslist{\par Lesson \arabic{chapter} -- \unexpanded{#2}\noexpand\begin{enumerate}}}
    {\eappto\masterieslist{\noexpand\end{enumerate}\par Lesson \arabic{chapter} -- \unexpanded{#2}\noexpand\begin{enumerate}}}}
\def\answer#1{\appto\masterieslist{\item#1}}

% for this example
\newcounter{question}[chapter]
\def\question{\stepcounter{question}\paragraph{Question~\thequestion}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{History of Computers}
\question In what year was the ABC computer made?
\answer{1939}
\question What does ENIAC stand for?
\answer{Electronic Numerical Integrator and Calculator}

\chapter{foo}
\question Whatever
\answer{answer one}
\question Whatsoever
\answer{answer two}

\clearpage
\printmasteries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Manuel, could you explain how it works or give a short exemple of your solution. As retupmoc258, I'm not a tex guru.

Comment: Done. It's definitely not a robust option, just a fast example that might give some ideas.

Comment: While I understand quite a lot about TeX at this point, I don't really understand the difference between expanded and not expanded.  I want to edit the formatting for the chapter headings, but I can't figure out how to do that without breaking the code.

Comment: Chapter headings are `\unexpanded{#2}`, so just add the formatting inside `\unexpanded{..}`. The reason to expand is to get the *current* value of the `chapter` counter.